# NodeJS 'request' module: HTTP POST returns 415

Tags: node.js, request

I am using the node module 'request' to make a POST request, and even after trying many different variations of content types, eg:

```
'content-type': 'application/json'
```

I am still getting a 415 (unsupported media type) response.  Below is my function:

```
var createNetworkResource = function (resourceName, inputDirectory) {
        request.post({url:browser.params.baseRestUrl + 'resources/connections', auth: browser.params.auth,
                form: {method:'POST', headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
                      displayName: "RESOURCE_TEST", name: "RESOURCE_TEST", type: "NETWORK",
        }},
            function(e,r,user){ console.log("Status code of createNetworkResource('" + resourceName + "'): " + r.statusCode);});
    };
```

I have tried different solutions from stackoverflow but none of them work and I could not find one specific to this node module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `form` property in [`request`](https://github.com/request/request#forms) sets the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Using `json: true` and specifying a `body: {}` will add a `Content-type: application/json` header and convert the request to a JSON string.

```
function createNetworkResource (resourceName, inputDirectory) {
  request.post({
      url: browser.params.baseRestUrl + 'resources/connections',
      auth: browser.params.auth,
      json: true,
      body: {
        displayName: "RESOURCE_TEST",
        name: "RESOURCE_TEST",
        type: "NETWORK"
      }
    },
    function(error, response, user){
      if (error) return console.error('error(%s):', resourceName, error)
      console.log("Status code of createNetworkResource(%s): %s", resourceName, response.statusCode)
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, I had to copy and paste a 'body' parameter example to get it to work (I guess I was missing some mandatory params).